# Uniform frame dropping on Lenovo C940 FHD (vsync issue?)

Tags: lenovo-laptop, intel-graphics, laptop-display

I recently got a Lenovo C940 notebook, the FHD option. The display is LG-made 1920x1080 IPS and EDID shows supported refresh rates of 60.020Hz and 47.999Hz. The graphics card is Intel Iris Plus (Intel Core i7-1065G7)

The problem is that both games and videos show a very strange frame dropping at precise regular intervals. It seems that one frame is dropped every ~0.5 seconds which causes as a slightly "jerky" motion. The effect is most visible when the scene is moving at a constant rate. The problem has nothing to do with CPU and GPU usage and I'm seeing it in both 2D and 3D games and even Netflix videos. The rate of frame drops is the same constant twice-per-second in both 60Hz and 48Hz modes, and is visible even when displaying 24fps content in 48Hz mode (which has 2 exact-same content frames for every refresh cycle).

The interval between vblank signals is fairly regular at ~16.66ms without any significant variance, as evident in Retroarch and vsynctester.com (both estimate the refresh rate by measuring the precise time between vblanks). On vsynctester.com I can see the VSYNC label flashing in red (and rarely cyan) at that dreaded constant rate but the history graph shows almost no variance, so it seems like the graphics card is pushing every frame but the *display* is dropping one every half second (if that's even possible).

Any other external monitor connected to the laptop works fine without any frame drops and vsynctester.com displays a nice, gray VSYNC label, even on a 2160p60 monitor via HDMI through a USB-C dongle. The problem is exactly the same on Windows 10, Linux on Wayland and Linux on Xorg, so I doubt that this is a driver issue, it seems like a hardware issue. I even tried creating other refresh rates using the CRU tool (59.96Hz, etc.) but all I get is a black screen.

BIOS is fully up-to-date. Any ideas on why is this happening and what can I try?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the culprit was an option of the Intel driver called "Panel Self Refresh". The option is in the "System" section, "Power" tab of the Intel Graphics Command center. I didn't pay it much mind since it's listed in the "On Battery" section and my problem was both when plugged in and on battery, but disabling it fixed the problem immediately and without even a restart.

The way to disable it on Linux is through a kernel parameter `i915.enable_psr=0`.